# Jenkins pipeline result metric analysis

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, automated-tests, jenkins-pipeline

I have a series of jenkins tests run as shell scripts using jenkins pipelines, with stages such as Build/Copy/TestSet1/Testset2. I'm hoping to be able to run a query such as "if result == fail && build == SUCCESS && TestSet1_runtime > 30s".

Right now this is being run through python scripts calling external binaries, but there aren't any junit reports being generated.

Is there a good method to get these results, even the raw data from the pipeline stages that I can parse?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [Jenkins tutorial](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#recording-test-results-and-artifacts), you can publish the tests results with something like this :

```
step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])
```

I'm not sure, however, that it is possible to get Junit results directly inside your pipeline to do the query you show. You could always parse your tests results for your specific needs, but that could be cumbersome.

Also, can you explain the context of your query ? It might be the case that you don't actually need to do this...

Comment: I don't have any Junit tests, it's not a part of my setup. I'm just running a python script which returns an an exit code if there's a test failure. I'd just like to be able to get information about the pipeline stage results for each run.